# Rewrite product URLs to category URLs

Tags: url-rewrite, seo

In our store we **only** use category URLs, i.e.

YES:  my-site.com/socks/the-ballers
NO:  my-size.com/the-ballers

I believe I have set the SEO settings correctly for this:

- Use Categories Path for Product URLs -> Yes
- Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed -> Yes
- Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Categories -> Yes
- Use Canonical Link Meta Tag For Products -> No

Also, *our products only appear in one category*.

We would like to go one step further and **make sure that product URLs are actually not accessible** and get rewritten to the category URLs so that they are not accessible, i.e.

REWRITE my-site.com/the-ballers ---> my-site.com/socks/the-ballers

How can I go about doing this such that it happens *automatically* when I reindex the URL Rewrites?

Comment: A product only appears in one category?

Comment: Yes, a product a appears in only one category.

Comment: @Melvyn URL Rewrite Management not working after Re-indexed For Category Redirect https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/210130/57334